# How to change default mouse cursor for the whole WPF application globally?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mouse-cursor

In my WPF application I am using only one mouse cursor.

Is there any way to change this cursor for the whole WPF application globally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Mouse.OverrideCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.overridecursor.aspx) method allows you to set the cursor for the entire application.